# Is it possible to reliably recover from a serial port IOException?

Tags: serial-port, ioexception

I'm running a Windows service that checks a hardware instrument approximately fifteen times a second, 24/7, on COM4. When the instrument receives a command it responds accordingly, ending its response with `>CRLF` to indicate round trip completion.

The following code is giving me some trouble:

```
01    Public Async Function SendAsync() As Task(Of Response)
02       Dim oResponse As Response
03       Dim sData As String
04 
05       Do
06         Me.Port.WriteLine(Me.Instruction)
07 
08         sData = Await ReadResponseAsync()
09         oResponse = New Response(Me.Instruction, sData)
10       Loop While oResponse.Status = Response.States.SyntaxError
11 
12       Return oResponse
13    End Function
14 
15    Private Async Function ReadResponseAsync() As Task(Of String)
16       Dim iSize As Integer
17       Dim sData As String
18       Dim aData As Byte()
19 
20       aData = New Byte(255) {}
21       sData = String.Empty
22 
23       Do
24         iSize = Await Me.Port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(aData, 0, aData.Length)
25         sData &= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(aData, 0, iSize)
26       Loop While Not sData.EndsWith($">{vbCrLf}")
27 
28       Return sData
29    End Function
```

I'm getting a rare `IOException` on line 24:

> System.IO.IOException: The I/O operation has been aborted because Of either a thread Exit Or an application request.

This has occurred twice in the past 144 hours, giving it a ratio of 1 in roughly 3.8mm challenge/response cycles. It doesn't correspond with any service stop actions.

Does this mean the data for that cycle is forever lost to me?

If I were to wrap the `ReadAsync()` call in a Try/Catch, like so, would the next loop pick up the waiting response?

```
Do
  Try
    iSize = Await Me.Port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(aData, 0, aData.Length)
    sData &= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(aData, 0, iSize)

  Catch ex As IOException
    Main.Logger.Warn("IOException was skipped. Data will be retrieved on next attempt.")

    aData = New Byte(255) {}
    sData = String.Empty

  End Try
Loop While Not sData.EndsWith($">{vbCrLf}")
```

I would like to spin up a quick test for this, but I'm unable to reproduce the `IOException` in context.